# Какой ЯП лучшего всего подходит для построения графиков?

Tags: любой-язык

Хотел сделать график нескольких акций, которые будет в режиме реального времени обновляться, в итоге написал программу на Python используя matplotlib, FuncAnimation, однако он ТАК медленно работает. Не подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть что-то более эффективное?

Если конкретнее, то каждую секунду проверяется стоимость нескольких акций, и при изменении цены также обновляется график. Чем больше графиков сразу можно так отображать и обновлять, тем лучше. Matplotlib не так эффективен, как хотелось бы, очень часто тормозит. Хотя, может это я так коряво код написал. Подумаю над этим, но вдруг вы знаете что-то мощнее, чем python и matplotlib?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Запустите профилирование и посмотрите на что тратится больше всего времени

Comment: А почему вы решили, что проблема именно в ЯП, а не в кривости вашего собственного кода? Запустите профилирование, действительно.

Comment: В мой профиль зайдите. В гитхабе есть пример свечных графиков на PyQt5. Работает точно быстрее, чем на Matplotlib. А вообще, чтобы быстро было это нужно делать на С++, но этот язык мне не знаком. Тот же PyQt это привязки Qt, написсанного на С++. Так же быстро работают графики, что отображаются в браузерах.